# Why typescript dose not check the param of interface method

Tags: typescript, interface

I have some code like this

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date, d2:Date);
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date) {
        this.currentTime = d;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

I hope typescript will give me an error like the method "setTime" should have two param, but it does not happen. Why?

Comment: It's probably perfectly valid to define another method with the same name with a different number of parameters. How is it supposed to know you intended to implement the interface and not just define another method?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand... if the interface cannot limit the parameters of the method, why we still write this code in the interface.

Comment: The interface is for when the code is used, not written. This isn't a Typescript specific "problem". This is why Java has a `@override` annotation, so the compiler can ensure that you're actually implementing the method properly.

Comment: Thanks. But I really want to restrict this method use two parameters with correct type, how can I do this....

Comment: It is a very common Javascript pattern to ignore possible function parameters, such as if Clock's setTime ultimately didn't care about `d2` so it just ignores that possible parameter. 

The Typescript team felt that this was a common enough pattern for Javascript developers that they made it so that you can always specify a smaller function header than what's required and it will type check.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare them inline you will see an error like this. the interface provides a basis and if you override the type it thinks you are not declaring that variable(function) since the types do not match

```
setTime:(a:Date,b:Date)=>Date;
setTime = (a: Date)=> { 
  return a;
}
```

`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'setTime' must be of type '(a: Date, b: Date) => Date', but here has type '(a: Date) => Date'.`